# Вывод URL из MySQL средствами PHP

Tags: php, чпу, mysql

Ребята, выручайте, бьюсь уже почти месяц над выводом чпу из MySQL средствами PHP. Имеем ссылку вида `сайт.ru/news.php?id_news=1`? через Rewrite сделал ссылку вида `сайт.ru/1`

Какой код нужно прописать в index.php для вывода из базы? Сейчас имею, но не работает:

```
<?php
$result = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (preg_match("/([^a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\-\_\#])/", $result)) {
    header("ХТТП/1.0 404 Not Found");
    echo "Недопустимые символы в URL";
    exit;
}
/* 
отбрасываем из ЧПУ всё лишнее, оставляя только имя 
виртуального html-файла. В случае с yourdomain.com/name-page.html 
это будет name-page функция preg_split формирует массив, 
разбивая переданную строку по заданной маске. 
*/
$array_url = preg_split("/(\/|\..*$)/", $result, 1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

if (!$array_url) {
    $id_news = 10;
} else {
    $sef_value = $array_url[0];
    /* 
    Далее идёт запрос в БД о наличие в столбце SEF строки $sef_value 
    при положительном ответе получаем из БД соответствующий $sef_value $ID_page, 
    если такой строки не найдено — выводим страницу ошибки 404. 
    */
}
/* 
Теперь обычная обработка, как если бы $ID_page был получен методом GET 
*/
require_once("config.php");
$query  = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE chpu = '" . $sef_value . "' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id_news = $row['id_news'];
} else {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    echo "Страница не существует";
    exit;
}
?>
```

p.s. chpu - колонка в бд, где хранится чпу. Мне надо брать url страницы вида `сайт.ru/s-chpu-luchhe/` из MySQL, а `mod_rewrite` - это всего лишь вырезать хурму (`news.php?id_news=`) из имеющегося `сайт.ru/news.php?id_news=1`.

Comment: @nero, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: А не проще погуглить на тему [.htaccess красивый url][1]? =)


  [1]: https://www.google.ru/#hl=ru&newwindow=1&sclient=psy-ab&q=.htaccess%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20url&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e3b0d9a2522d0d56&biw=1600&bih=768&pf=p&pdl=300

Answer (score 2):

Более практичный подход использования Rewrite выглядит так:

Наример для апача:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Таким образом все запросы будут перенаправляться на index.php, а в нём уже средствами РНР разгребаем $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. Но лучше юзать готовый фреймворк ;)

Comment: Всмысле я так и делаю но при перенаправлении на index.php код который имеею и представлен выше отказывается работать